# Inserting a new route into the RouteTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to insert a route into the route table but can't work out how to do it.

For example I have a route mapped as below:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", 
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

However I want to insert that same route into the route table using the syntax below. How do I do it?

```
RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0, new Route(
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of thinking I found the way to do it:

```
        Route myRoute = new Route("", new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" }, {"id", UrlParameter.Optional }}, new MvcRouteHandler());
        RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0, myRoute);
```

Comment: How would you add Constraints to this?

Answer (score 0):

The routes you have there is the RouteTable.Routes and by MapRoute this is being added to the tables.  You can only add each route once.

Comment: Hi Dove, I wasn't looking to duplicate the route, rather I was trying to insert the route using the new Route() method instead of the MapRoute() method.

Comment: just curious, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm using a CMS that builds its own entries in the route table and i want to insert a route at the very beginning of the route table so the CMS is ignored in certain circumstances